# How can I properly implement JPImagePickerController in my code?

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, picker

I've had some issues trying to get the JPImagePickerController working in my code.

Anyone find any guides on how to do it (I can't find a single one)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Demo worked fine for me... [check it out](http://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController/tree/master/JPImagePickerDemo/).  You could also download the actual source and play around with it if you are having troubles.